# OpenALSDKInstaller Download Not Working For OSX?

Tags: macos, sdk, installation, openal

Does anyone else get an error when trying to download the mac openALSDKInstaller from http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Downloads/Forms/AllItems.aspx ? Is there anywhere else to download the mac version of the SDK? There are many places to download the PC SDK but I can't find any for mac...

Comment: It is easily downloading. What is the exact problem you facing? Download the dmg file, and install it.

Comment: Are you maybe talking about the OpenAL_Installer_OSX? I can get that dmg just fine, but the when I click on either on of the SKD links I get a window that says 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Comment: When we hover over it, there is a menu popup. Click on it, select Send, Click on download a copy, asks for a username and password.